# How do I use WMI with Delphi without drastically increasing the application's file size?

Tags: delphi, wmi

I am using Delphi 2010, and when I created a console application that prints "Hello World", it takes 111 kb. If I want to query WMI with Delphi, I add WBEMScripting_TLB, ActiveX, and Variants units to my project. If I perform a simple WMI query, my executable size jumps to 810 kb. I

Is there anyway to query WMI without such a large addition to the size of the file? Forgive my ignorance, but why do I not have this issue with C++?

Here is my code:

```
program WMITest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  WBEMScripting_TLB,
  ActiveX,
  Variants;

function GetWMIstring(wmiHost, root, wmiClass, wmiProperty: string): string;
var
  Services: ISWbemServices;
  SObject: ISWbemObject;
  ObjSet: ISWbemObjectSet;
  SProp: ISWbemProperty;
  Enum: IEnumVariant;
  Value: Cardinal;
  TempObj: OLEVariant;
  loc: TSWbemLocator;
  SN: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  i := 0;
  try
    loc := TSWbemLocator.Create(nil);
    Services := Loc.ConnectServer(wmiHost, root {'root\cimv2'}, '', '', '', '',
      0, nil);
    ObjSet := Services.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM ' + wmiClass, 'WQL',
      wbemFlagReturnImmediately and wbemFlagForwardOnly, nil);
    Enum := (ObjSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    if not VarIsNull(Enum) then
      try
        while Enum.Next(1, TempObj, Value) = S_OK do
        begin
          try
            SObject := IUnknown(TempObj) as ISWBemObject;
          except SObject := nil;
          end;
          TempObj := Unassigned;
          if SObject <> nil then
          begin
            SProp := SObject.Properties_.Item(wmiProperty, 0);
            SN := SProp.Get_Value;
            if not VarIsNull(SN) then
            begin
              if varisarray(SN) then
              begin
                for i := vararraylowbound(SN, 1) to vararrayhighbound(SN, 1) do
                  result := vartostr(SN[i]);
              end
              else
                Result := SN;
              Break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        SProp := nil;
      except
        Result := '';
      end
    else
      Result := '';
    Enum := nil;
    Services := nil;
    ObjSet := nil;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Result := e.message;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    WriteLn('hello world');
    WriteLn(GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_OperatingSystem',
      'Caption'));
    WriteLn('done');

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**UPDATE:**
When I compile the [following sample from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (console application), it is 76 kb.

Comment: When you say "with C++", what C++ compiler are you using?  C++ Builder?  Visual C++?  GCC?  What version?

Comment: Why is "a console application that prints 'Hello World'" any sort of meaningful data point for executable size?

Comment: It's a frame of reference for non-Delphi users that may be familiar with solving the problem using C/C++.

Comment: C++ compiler is VS 2008. When I compile similar samples from MSDN, the size is 76 kb: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: VS2008... you probably have some kind of runtime DLLs to deploy with your exe.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

@Mick, you can access the WMI without import the WBEMScripting from Delphi, using the [IBindCtx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693755%28VS.85%29.aspx) and  [IMoniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679705%28VS.85%29.aspx) interfaces.

Check this simple code (Tested in Delphi 2010 and Windows 7), the exe file size is 174 kb.

```
program WmiTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  SysUtils
  ,ActiveX
  ,ComObj
  ,Variants;


function GetWMIstring(wmiHost, root, wmiClass, wmiProperty: string): string;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;//for access to a bind context
    Moniker: IMoniker;//Enables you to use a moniker object
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));//Converts a string into a moniker that identifies the object named by the string
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));//Binds to the specified object
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject(Format('winmgmts:\\%s\%s',[wmiHost,root]));
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT * FROM %s',[wmiClass]),'WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do 
  begin
     Result:=colItem.Properties_.Item(wmiProperty, 0); //you can improve this code  ;) , storing the results in an TString.
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try         
      WriteLn(GetWMIstring('.', 'root\CIMV2', 'Win32_OperatingSystem','Caption'));
      Readln;
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    Begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
        Readln;
    End;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: @IanBoyd check this article [Accesing the WMI from Object Pascal Code (Delphi, Oxygene, FreePascal)](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/accesing-the-wmi-from-pascal-code-delphi-oxygene-freepascal/)

Comment: There is a MEMORY LEAK in GetWMIObject(): StringToOleStr(objectName) doesn't have matching SysFreeString(objectName)!

Answer (score 6):

ActiveX and/or Variants would add 36KB at most.
It's **WBEMScripting_TLB** that **adds** about **650KB** to your project.
It's not huge in lines of code but more than declaring quite a few classes, interfaces and constants, it **includes OleServer** in its uses.
And ***THAT brings the whole* `Controls` *unit*** with its ***heavy baggage***.

Comment: True.  Then again, this is hardly "heavy baggage" anymore.  Heck, the entire "drastically increased" executable would still fit on a 1.44 MB floppy!

Comment: Seeing it that way... Still, it's a factor 7 increase, and it would not fit anymore on 360K floppy - the ones that actually flop. :-)

Answer (score 2):

when delphi builds an executable, it statically links in the delphi runtime libraries.  this results in a larger executable, however as the rtl is statically linked, deployment is easier, and there's an element of future proofing.

you can configure delphi to use runtime packages by enabling `Build with runtime packages` in the `Project` / `Options`.  however you'll have to ensure the delphi rtl packages are available, and you may encounter issues with debugging.

this static vs runtime linking behaviour probably explains the differences you're seeing between delphi and c++.

Answer (score 1):

The difference you're seeing, in part anyway, is because VC++ uses dynamically linked runtime libraries by default; the runtime libraries are loaded from DLLs when the app runs, and therefore the code isn't present in the executable.

Delphi, OTOH, by default links in all of the runtime library code unless you build with runtime packages enabled. This difference in default configurations will account for the majority of the size differences between the executables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about WBEMScripting_TLB, but ActiveX.pas is a pretty huge unit.  It's almost 7000 lines on my D2010 install.  If you have to bring any significant amount of that into your code, then you can expect it will add a few hundred K to your EXE size.

How big is the TLB, by the way?